# GCP pub/sub client is failing above version 4.0.0 with auth error

Tags: node.js, typescript, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

This happens when I try to create a topic

```
   TypeError: this.auth.getUniverseDomain is not a function
        at GrpcClient.createStub (/Users/<...>/node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:418:48)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Sample Code:

```
pubSubClient = new PubSub({
      "projectId": "project_name"
    });

initTopic = async () => {
    // Creates a new topic if it does not exist
    const [topics] = await this.pubSubClient.getTopics()
    RootLogger.info("topic names: " + topics.join(","))
    const topicExists = topics.some(topic => topic.name.endsWith(this.topicName));

    if (topicExists) {
      RootLogger.info(`Topic ${this.topicName} already exists.`);
    } else {
      await this.pubSubClient.createTopic(this.topicName);
      RootLogger.info(`Topic ${this.topicName} created.`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Same problem, started about a week ago without any meaningful code changes.

Comment: I have fixed it by downgrading to 3.7

Comment: The issue is opened on github in the google auth package.
[link 1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/1702)
[link 2](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1884)
[link 3](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1887)

Comment: The third one was raised by me :P

Comment: Hi @vizsatiz , I have just posted your comment as a community workaround answer to help anyone who is facing the same issue. You can also consider creating a ticket in the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Answer (score 2):

As @vizsatiz mentioned in the comment:

> The error `TypeError: this.auth.getUniverseDomain is not a function` was solved by downgrading it to 3.7. The problem occurred when using the pub/sub client above version 4.0.0.  As a workaround, anyone facing the same issue with the version above 4.0.0 can consider downgrading the version as a first step.

Posting the answer as `community wiki` for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.